# class method hid intentionally warrning

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i use following code it not give me warring . . .

```
 class Employee
{
    public string FName;
    public string LName;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FName + " " + LName);
    }
}

class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FName + " " + LName + " - From FullTimeEmployee Class . . .");
    }
}

class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FullTimeEmployee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
        FTE.FName = "FullTime";
        FTE.LName = "Employee";
        FTE.Print();

        PartTimeEmployee PTE = new PartTimeEmployee();
        PTE.FName = "PartTime";
        PTE.LName = "Employee";
        PTE.Print();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

but when i made employee class as public it shows that .. Warning       'FullTimeEmployee.Print()' hides inherited member 'Employee.Print()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
Why is this so....???

Comment: because you are using the same name for method  in base class and child class.

Comment: Because method name is same in dervied and parent class. You need to override method then

Comment: this link will give you a clear idea http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18733/Method-Hiding-in-C

Comment: because you are having same method name as in the base class so that implementation is hide. and compiler warns you. to avoid warning compiler is asking for the new keyword ahead of method signature of method who hides base implementation.

Comment: then why compiler do not warn me when i don't use public in front of Employee class..??

Comment: @SandeepGaikwad the code in question would have to report warning on the method `Print` of `FullTimeEmployee`. Check it twice and confirm it. If it does not report it is magic :)

Comment: @JenishRabadiya you are right this is a simple OOPs concept. The key is that you're not overriding the method. You're hiding it. If you were overriding it, you'd need the override keyword (at which point, unless it's virtual, the compiler would complain because you can't override a non-virtual method).You use the new keyword to tell both the compiler and anyone reading the code, "It's okay, I know this is only hiding the base method and not overriding it - that's what I meant to do."

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Yes it gives warring but only when i wright public in front of Employee class else it don't .. I understand what to do but i don't understand why ..?

Comment: I am just using copy of your code without using public. I am still getting the warning.

Comment: Sunny's comment and upvote on that comment says you are doing something wrong. It's not magic... :)

Comment: @sunny,@JenishRabadiya I want to show you my program but i am not able to do so... how can i share image of it...??

Comment: Hey guys you are right it does shows warring but at that time you re build it then warring is gone... It means if u build a project an it shows warring then if you rebuild project instantly warring is gone....

Answer (score -1):

Use Virtual and Override. You can override parent class method with child class method in this way. Or you can hide it using new operator before child class method

```
 class Employee
{
public string FName;
public string LName;

public virtual  void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FName + " " + LName);
}
}

class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public override  void Print()
     {
    Console.WriteLine(FName + " " + LName + " - From FullTimeEmployee Class . . .");
   }
}

class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{

}

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    FullTimeEmployee FTE = new FullTimeEmployee();
    FTE.FName = "FullTime";
    FTE.LName = "Employee";
    FTE.Print();

    PartTimeEmployee PTE = new PartTimeEmployee();
    PTE.FName = "PartTime";
    PTE.LName = "Employee";
    PTE.Print();

    Console.Read();
}
}
```